# Possible to edit an append value?

Tags: python

i want to edit a value i have insert with append, is it possible ?

Exemple:

```
list = []

list.append[myuserid, 'true']
```

Now i want to edit this for change value true by false for exemple, how i can do this ?

I have try:

```
for data in list:
    if data == [myuserid, 'true']:
        data = [myuserid, 'false']
```

But now if i print data i have this:

```
[myuserid, 'true'], [myuserid, 'false']
```

I want to change the existing value.. not add a more values :/ have you a solution please ?

Comment: First don't call your lists `list` this is a python builtin method. Then, just use `my_list[-1]` to access the last element

Comment: Your code is invalid. `list.append[myuserid, 'true']` is not valid Python.

Comment: Your example is not valid python. Are you talking about dictionaries instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is invalid. `list.append[myuserid, 'true']` is not valid Python.

I think what you are trying to use is a [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

```py
idDict = {}

idDict['someID1'] = True
idDict['someID2'] = False

for key in idDict:
    if idDict[key] == True:
        print(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use a dictionary? you could store the username as a key in a dict and then store a boolean as the value, you can then take advantage of the no operator to flip the value

```py
myuserid="userA"

users = {
    myuserid: True
}

for _ in range(5):
    print(f"{users[myuserid]=}")
    users[myuserid] = not users[myuserid]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
users[myuserid]=True
users[myuserid]=False
users[myuserid]=True
users[myuserid]=False
users[myuserid]=True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change list items, by using its index:

```
lst = []
myuserid = 'myuserid'
lst.append([myuserid, 'true'])

for idx, data in enumerate(lst):
    # idx is the index(position), starting from 0. Data holds the actual value
    if data == [myuserid, 'true']:
        lst[idx] = [myuserid, 'false']
print(data)
```

Out:

```
['myuserid', 'true']
```